# pygsr TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run this code in python 3.4:

```
from pygsr import Pygsr
speech = Pygsr()
# duration in seconds
speech.record(3)
# select the language
phrase, complete_response = speech.speech_to_text('en_UK')

print(phrase)`
```

but I get the error

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygsr/__init__.py", line 33, in record
    for i in range(0, self.rate / self.chunk * time):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Any ideas as to why? I haven't modified the code apart from changing 'es_ES' to 'en_UK' from the pygsr PyPi site.

Comment: people will probably vote me down but my suggestion would be to use numpy.arange, instead http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `pysgr` was written in Python 2.7 (*[see source code](https://bitbucket.org/drneox/pygsr/src/d2902fe8083b123e8a3009dc08fb6c80b353e025/pygsr.py?fileviewer=file-view-default)*), where dividing integers gives you an integer by flooring. In Python 3.4 as you are using, dividing integers can return a float (*see [PEP 238 - Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)*) which results in your error, as `range()` requires integer parameters.

Comment: So it can only run on 2.7? Thought I saw 3.4 in documentation! My bad! Thank alot!

Comment: It can probably safely run on < Python3.x, or you could always attempt to modify it with things like the floor division operator `//` to support Python 3.x.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I'll have a read into floor division

Comment: @JONAS402 I wouldn't necessarily recommend modifying it, you may end up digging through source code with other issues (although perhaps not, I haven't checked).

Comment: Ok maybe I'll stick to 2.7 then thanks for the heads up